# How to check whether a user created successfully in Django

Tags: python, django

I was trying Django and I used this code to create a user

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    

def register(request):
    user = User.objects.create_user('John', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
    user.last_name = "James"
    user.is_active = True
    status = user.save()
    return HttpResponse(status)
```

My question is how can I check whether a user is successfully created or not and also to display an error message, if I am unable to create a user. 
When I run this code, it creates a user but returns a value `None`

Thanks

Comment: `user.save()` is just a function to save the user wont return anything and so `None`.

Comment: Django uses exceptions to communicate that it failed to save an object. If you don't catch them, the exception will bubble up, and Django will return a 500 response in the case of a failure.

Comment: Looks like currently you are at perfect stage to start mastering Django's testing framework. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create_user` will rise integrity error if such user already exists.

```
def register(request):
    try:
        user = User.objects.create_user('John', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
    except IntegrityError:
        # user already exists
        status = 'user already exists'
    else:
        user.last_name = "James"
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        status = 'new user was created'
    return HttpResponse(status)
```

This looks better for me:

```
def register(request):
    try:
        # user is active bu default
        user = User.objects.create_user('John', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword', last_name='James')
    except IntegrityError:
        # user already exists
        status = 'user already exists'
    else:
        status = 'new user was created'
    return HttpResponse(status)
```

Comment: Should the `status = 'new user was created'` be in an `else` block? At the moment it'll always be run.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the user has a `pk` attribute with an actually value. If it does it's saved in the database.

As user knbk stated below as simple check like the following will be enough

```
if user.pk is not None: # do stuff
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more explanation. How to check that?

Comment: `if user.pk is not None`, but the user will already have a pk since `create_user()` saves it to the database.

Comment: Thanks a lot @knbk, but how do we check whether that username already exist?

Comment: @nitroman `username` has `unique=True`, so the database enforces that all usernames are unique. If you try to save a new user with an existing username, it will raise an `IntegrityError`. See zymud's answer on how to handle that.